# What's the right way to have two different webserver (nginx and caddy) containers replying to the same domain?

Tags: docker, nginx, traefik, caddy

I am trying to test different web servers on the same website and docker host.
I tried to launch both the containers with the same website root and same front-end traefik label, but it seems that only one of the two gets pointed. The second one doesn't get any request. It starts replying only if I stop the other one, so looks like it's working in a sort of fail over.

What is the right and proper way to achieve this kind of result? Thank you!

Comment: Can you please include a description of what you've tried so far? Include the docker file and the configurations of the webservers.

Comment: You need two different domain names if they are supposed to respond on the same port (IP works as one of the names), or you need two different network interfaces. If You use two different domain names You need to put one web server behind the other one. Would this do or are You doing anything performance related testing that requires you to have them not proxy each other?

Comment: Sure: docker run -d --restart=unless-stopped --name nginx -l traefik.enable=true -l traefik.frontend.rule=Host:www.domain.com nginx:alpine for the first container and docker run -d --restart=unless-stopped --name caddy -l traefik.enable=true -l traefik.frontend.rule=Host:www.domain.com -l traefik.port=2015 for the second one. What I'd expect is traefik to load balance the traffic, while Caddy seems to receive all the traffic while both active.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found out. All I need to specify is "-l traefik.backend=domain.com" on both the containers, so they know they're both backends for the same domain.